# UDP from Mobile Device to Azure

Tags: tcp, azure, udp

I am woking on a Mobile application, which sends GPS co-ordinates from the mobile to an azure website.

Right now I am able to do this using TCP endpoints in Azure Web/Worker Role. The Mobile hardware I am using is SIM300 module.

SIM300 also provides sending data via UDP, which is much simpler, faster for my application.

I have heard Azure Connect uses UDP to communicate between local and virtual machines through UDP.

I am not sure, but is there any way to implement the same application to use UDP instead of TCP in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get UDP to work over the service bus using a UDP -> TCP tunnel. But as Simon says, you're better off using TCP if you can.

http://coderead.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/tunnelling-udp-over-the-service-bus-or-how-to-get-sentinel-licencing-server-working-on-azure/

Comment: That is cool/scary, but why not use Azure connect, which creates a tunnel? Is it because your licensing server is non Windows?

Comment: No, it's just because I didn't want to use Connect! Maybe I should try that out instead...

Answer (score 0):

Azure doesn't support public UDP endpoints (yet). The only current alternative is to use an non-Azure server that listens on UDP and, via Windows Azure Connect, forwards it to the 'internal' endpoint. Since your device already uses TCP anyway, I would stick with that for now.